# How to change value in html through Events

Tags: html, typescript, ionic2

Im trying to get value by using Events(ionic), once it listen to my 'onSMSArrive'. Actually, i get the value from events. The problem is, it not change the value in my app.

Here is my code in app.component.ts

```
this.events.publish('sms', this.word);
```

It will go to my home.ts

```
  events.subscribe('sms', (word) => {

     alert("word: " + word); //it really get the value
     this.word = word;
  });
```

My home.html

```
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="word"></ion-input>
```

But weird, when i trigger the app to background (not kill), then open it again.It did change the value. any idea?

Comment: What is your `ChangeDetectionStrategy` using?

Answer (score 0):

I guess [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) will solve your problem

Use it like below

```
  constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

**Then in your code**

```
 events.subscribe('sms', (word) => {

       alert("word: " + word); //it really get the value
       this.word = word;
       this.ref.markForCheck();  //added
  });
```